# Creating a single die roll program in Java, but rather than rolling 300 times, it is rolling 320 times

Tags: java, dice

I have been trying to find where the error is in this code for some time now and I just can't figure it out. The program is rolling a 6 sided die 300 times, and then outputting the number of time each number is rolled. But for some reason, rather than rolling it 300 times, it's rolling 320 times. I don't see anything wrong with the for-loop so I'm really at a loss here.

```
public static void dieRoll(){
    int[] roll = new int [300];
    int[] count = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    for(int i = 1; i<300; i++){
            roll[i] = (int) Math.ceil( (int) (Math.random()*6)+1 );

//          roll[i] = (int) Math.ceil(roll[i]);
//          System.out.println(roll[i]);

            if(roll[i]==1){
                count[0]++;
            }
            else if(roll[i]==2){
                count[1]++;
            }
            else if(roll[i]==3){
                count[2]++;
            }
            else if(roll[i]==4){
                count[3]++;
            }
            else if(roll[i]==5){
                count[4]++;
            }
            else if(roll[i]==6){
                count[5]++;
            }

        //  System.out.println(roll[i]);

    }//i loop   

    System.out.println("The die landed on 1 " + count[0] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die landed on 2 " + count[1] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die landed on 3 " + count[2] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die landed on 4 " + count[3] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die landed on 5 " + count[4] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die landed on 6 " + count[5] + " times.");
    System.out.println("The die was rolled this many times: " + (count[0]+count[1]+count[2]+count[3]+count[4]+count[5]));

}//dieRoll()
```

If someone could just please point me out to where the error might be manifesting itself, that would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: If you do that last println *before* you enter the loop, you'll see the problem. Your `count` array is starting with non-zero values.

Answer (score 13):

You initialised your counts like this:

```
int[] count = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Now, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 is equal to 21.  Your loop goes from 1 to 299, which is 299 iterations.  And of course, 299 + 21 is 320.

You should initialise your array to all zeros.

Finally, your code can be simplified:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 300; i++ )
{
    roll[i] = (int) Math.ceil( (int) (Math.random()*6)+1 );
    count[roll[i] - 1]++;
}
```